# How to calculate non-intersecting area of 3+ equal circles?

Tags: circles, area

Here is the image what i'm trying to do.

[image]

I want to calculate the area of pink area. As you can see the circles have the same radius and their positions are known.

I've already tried calculating intersecting area of two circles and just do: `fullArea - intersectArea / 2`. But this doesn't working on more than two circles because intersection areas might overlap how you can see on image.

So basically i need to calculate intersection of intersections. Or what? Also i have much more than 3 circles but i don't think that it matters.

I need this to calculate the area of circle that i scratched. Basically i have big circle for scratch and many inside when scratching. A have to calculate if small circles occupy more than 75 percent of big.

The calculations have to be done in computer program.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please be careful with the choice of your tags. This question is *not* about `intersection-theory`.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Sorry. Already deleted.

Comment: In your picture the circles seem to have the same radius. Please edit the question to specify the input data more clearly: what restrictions are there on the centers and the radii? And tell us too why you need to know that area. Will an algorithm do, or must you have  a formula. Your profile suggests this may be for a game.

Comment: Is there a definite pattern for the location of the centers?

Comment: Principle of Inclusion and Exclusion type of computation?

Comment: @EthanBolker i specified it in question.

Comment: @quasi edited question.

Comment: The key, as Malcolm commented, is the principle of inclusion-exclusion, but unless you have a simple pattern for the centers, it's a computational disaster. Just knowing the centers is not enough to make the computation easy.

Comment: @quasi so it's impossible if a have only positions and radiuses are equal?

Comment: I didn't say it was impossible. Just too complicated to do without a computer program, and no reasonable closed-form formula is likely. On the other hand, if there is a simple geometric pattern to where the centers are located, then you might be able to get a closed-form result.

Comment: @quasi i have to do this in code.

Comment: How many circles?

Comment: @quasi unknown. Unique every time

Comment: What is the range of the number of circles? In particular, what is the _max_ number?

Comment: Can't say exactly. Think not more than 25. If need i can control that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are given as input, a large number of circles (e.g., possibly as many as $25$) in the $xy$-plane, of equal radius.

The common radius is specified, as well as the locations of the centers, presumably with all numerical values given in decimal format.

The goal is to compute the area of the portion of some specified disk (the pink disk) which does not intersect the union of the other disks.

Assuming the locations of the centers is *arbitrary*, with no pattern known in advance, I think the best approach is to approximate the area via a simulation.

Here is an outline . . .

Let $r$ be the given radius, and let $(h,k)$ be the center of the pink disk.

Start by bounding the pink disk, as tight as possible, in a square $S$ of side length $2r$, given algebraically by
\begin{cases}
h-r \le \;x\; \le h+r\\[4pt]
k-r \le \;y\; \le k+r\}\\
\end{cases}
Next, initialize a variable $w=0$.

Loop $n$ times, where $n$ is large, say $n=10^6$.

In each iteration:

- Choose a uniformly random point $P\in S$.$\\[2pt]$

  Determine algebraically whether or not $P$ is in the pink disk. If $P$ is not in the pink disk, skip to the next iteration.

  Set a variable overlap=false.$\\[2pt]$

  In an inner loop, for each disk $D$ other than the pink disk, determine algebraically whether or not $P\in D$. If $P\in D$, set overlap=true, and exit the inner loop.$\\[2pt]$

  Back in the main loop, if overlap is false, set $w=w+1$.$\\[2pt]$

When the loop is complete:

- The approximate area of the (visible) pink region is $\bigl({\large{\frac{w}{n}}}\bigr)(4r^2)$.